# same LogisticRegression.coef_ list for 2 different LogisticRegression.classes_

Tags: python, logistic-regression

`model.coef_` is of shape (1,4) - so 1 row and 4 columns. Each one of the 4 columns is a regression coefficient. My question is: Why is`model.coef_` storing just one set of coefficients i.e. coefficients only for `model.classes_[1] = 'Survived'`

```
model = LogisticRegression().fit(featureVecs, labels)
for i in range(len(model.coef_)):
            print (model.coef_.shape)
            print (model.classes_.shape)
            print('For label', model.classes_[1])
            for j in range(len(model.coef_[0])): 
                print('   ', Passenger.featureNames[j], '=', model.coef_[0][j])
```

I get the following `model.coef_` array for `model.classes_[1] = 'Survived'`

```
C2 = -1.08337751448
C3 = -1.92236816902
age = -0.0260808084178
male gender = -2.36271941114
```

`model.classes_` is of shape (2,) - so `model.classes_ = ['Died' 'Survived']`

When attempting to get the coefficient results for `model.classes_[0] = 'Died'`, I changed the code above slightly to:

```
for i in range(len(model.coef_)):
            print (model.coef_.shape)
            print (model.classes_.shape)
            print('For label', model.classes_[1])
            for j in range(len(model.coef_[0])): 
                print('   ', Passenger.featureNames[j], '=', model.coef_[1][j])
```

It obviously errors out because `model.coef_` is a of shape (1,4). So the question becomes - How do I get the co-officients for `model.classes_[0] = 'Died'`

Comment: There is only one set of coefficients- you don't get separate coefficients for one class vs. the other. What are you trying to do?

Comment: So these current coefficients included above give me the likelihood for 'Survived' - I am also interested in the likelihood for 'Died' for C2, C3, age, male gender. These coefficients should be different for 'Survived' and 'Died'. I would imagine that 'Survived' and 'Died' would be dummy variables with values of 1 or 0 depending upon which of the two we are looking at.

Comment: Keep in mind that `probably('Died') = (1 - probability('Surivived'))`.

Comment: Sorry - but could you elaborate on how to get the new coefficients for the 'Died' scenario

Comment: There are no new coefficients. A [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) is a binary classifier- which means it produces an output which represents the probability of an binary outcome- for instance dead vs. survived. The coefficients give us insight into how much a particular feature increases the likelihood (or [odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds)) of whichever of these is defined as the positive outcome (as you said dummy values of 1 and 0). However, there are only two possible outcomes so their probabilities must sum to one.

Comment: The overall probability is x and (1-x). How will I get the coefficients of C2, C3, age for the 'Died' scenario? The problem is - in the Logistic Regression above, I did not specify anywhere that I am looking for the Probability of 'Survival' - how did the code assume that 'Survived' is what I am interested in. The 'labels' argument includes both 'Survived' and 'Died'. I want to measure the individual effect of each coefficient. How did the code decide which dummy variable ('Died' or 'Survived') to substitute 1 or a 0 for? Maybe - if I could build the regression equation itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168141/discussion-between-user1-and-pault).